# ng-init is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to initialize model value as per the column value of the grid. 
I have this object which I want initialize using ng-init. but when I see in the
ng inspector, model value is always undefined. AID is dynamic value in the kendo grid.

```
   <input type="checkbox" ng-init=""obj['#: AID#']='Y'"" ng-model=""obj['#: AID#']"">
```

controller:

```
 var testController = function($scope){
        $scope.obj= {};
 }
```

this is how final markup looks like

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="ps['test']=('Y' == 'N')" ng-model="ps['test']" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
```

I expect the model  ps['test'] to be false. But it is always undefined. 
Please help

Comment: are those double double quotes on ng-init and ng-model correct?

Comment: yes. It is correct. I am embedding this from code behind

Comment: So you are expecting `ng-init` to evaluate to `false`, and then be stored in `$scope.performswitch['S10000000032']`? Seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/f1yIAw7athS7UGEAP2ig?p=preview

Comment: sorry I have a watch on another model which is overriding this model. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the value to true or false, instead of Y or N. Like below

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="obj['m']=true" ng-model="obj['m']">
```